# Formatear String to Float

Tags: java

Tengo las siguienets cadenas:  1,523.26 y 185,123,589.56 y me gustaria convertirlo a Float

Imagino que tendre que usar un formateador pero me gustraía que sea generico tanto si uso miles (1,666.22) o millones (1,666,666.22)

He visto este post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885254/string-format-to-format-double-in-java pero devuelve un String y no se si es tan genérico

Comment: si te fijas en el parametro que pasa no tiene comas

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas convertir la cadena a Float, en realidad no necesitas un formateador, lo importante aquí es quitar los ",", para poder convertir mediante `Float.parseFloat(...)` tu cadena.

Puedes usar el siguiente método que como ves al inicio reemplaza el caracter "," :

```
private Float convertToFloat(String valor){
    valor = valor.replace(",","");
    Float valorDouble = Float.parseFloat(valor);
    Float valorFloat = new Float(valorDouble);

    return valorFloat;
}
```

de esta forma podrías llamar el método:

```
Float valor1 = convertToFloat("1,523.26");
Float valor2 =  convertToFloat("185,123,589.56");
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto.

```
float numero=Float.parseFloat(variable);
```

lo que puedes hacer por si ingresan miles o millones, me sale la idea que lo hagas con un ciclo, y cuentas los digitos, segun los digitos le aplicas algo de esta forma "%1$,.2f"

Comment: Float.parseFloat es lo que uso, pero cuando ya tiene las comas no funciona

Comment: Ya intentaste eliminar las comas y después convertirlo?

Comment: cadena.replaceAll("[^,-.]", "") y después lo conviertes a float

Comment: si podria hacer el replace pero era por si habia alguna forma mas "elegante de hacerlo"